# How to express that a graph has Independent set of size at least $n/2$ in $\exists SO$

Tags: graphs, logic, finite-model-theory, independent-sets

I am looking to provide a formula saying "A graph with $n$ vertices has an independent set $X$ of size at least $n/2$" in existentional second order logic.

(This is exercise 1.2. from Libkin's Elements of Finite Model Theory (see [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Elibkin/fmt/fmt.pdf) for online pdf, page 10 of the book (or 23 in the pdf)).

I can express that $X$ is an independent set as follows (assume that our vocabulary containts just one binary relational symbol $E$  for the edge relation):

$$
\exists X (\forall x\forall y : X(x) \wedge X(y) \Rightarrow \neg E(x,y))
$$
However, how to express that $X$ is of size at least $n/2$?

There is a simillar example with bipartite subgraph with at least $m/2$ edges ($m$ is the number of total edges) in the same exercise.

E: For the bipartite subgraph, in fact, this is true in general, so a formula like $\forall x\colon x=x$ would describe all graphs that have bipartite subgraph with at least $m/2$ edges, however, is it expressible really as it is -- without knowing that it is in fact valid for all graphs?

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see it is to notice that asking for $|X|\ge n/2$ is the same as asking that $X$ is bigger than $V(G)\setminus X$, which can be witnessed by an injection from $V(G)\setminus X$ to $X$. Thus, the property can be expressed in the following way:

$$
\begin{align*}
|X|\ge n/2 &\iff |V\setminus X|\le|X| \\
&\iff \exists F: V\setminus X \hookrightarrow X \\
&\iff \exists F \left(\ \forall x\forall y: F(x)\neq F(y)\ \wedge\ \forall x: \neg X(x)\implies X(F(x))\ \right)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I think, to be more pedantic, we should express $F$ to be a binary predicate satisfying the axioms of a function, e.g. $\forall x \exists ! y : F(x,y)$, then injectivity would look like $\forall x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 : (F(x_1,y_1)\wedge  F(x_2,y_2)\Rightarrow y_1=y_2\Rightarrow x_1=x_2)$. But I guess we can always make this shortcut and in fact quantify over function symbols.

Anyways, this is the idea I was looking for, tyvm.

Comment: Yes you're right, what you wrote is better, for some reason when I briefly skimmed through the pdf I thought they allowed this kind of shortands but that's not the case and now I see that $X$ and $F$ having the same arity is kind of confusing.